# Not able to get the element with XDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

Below is the code i am using to get the value of the 'name'(attribute) of the 'person'

parameter tag="person" and parameter attribute="name"

```
public static string GetInformationFromXML(string tag,
                                           string attribute,
                                           string filePath)
{
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        string info = doc.Element(tag).Attribute(attribute).Value;

        return info;
}
```

doc.Element(tag) is not getting the element even though when i expand doc, it does have an element with type 'Element' and Name 'person'
the file being read is XmlDocument for your information.

below is the xml of the file i am trying to read

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<import>
  <company name1="ABC" name2="" action="create" 
           profile="\Profiles\ABC\" id="C1">
    <address street="industrial" city="london" 
             country="england" id="A1">
      <telecom type="phone" value="4839282992" 
               desc="" default="true" />
      <telecom type="fax" value="3232" desc="" />
    </address>
  </company>
  <person title="Mr." name="Tariq" surname="sheikh" 
          lang="EN" action="create"  profile="Profiles\Tariq" 
          login="tariq" password="123456" default_address="A1">
    <link reference="C1" type="Employee" description="Software developer" />
    <address street="baker street" zip="12443" 
             city="london" country="england" />
    <account bank="Barclays" account="4378734834" />
    <telecom type="email" value="tariq.sheikh@abc.co.in" desc="" />
    <registration type="temporaryID" 
                  value="4623648c-739e-49c8-93fa-41dc7fed53ea" />
  </person>
</import>
```

I am new to XDocument !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Descendants` when element you're looking for is not direct child of current element (or root for `XDocument`).

```
string info = doc.Descendants(tag).First().Attribute(attribute).Value;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i want to confirm that in case i have to go inside nested tags to any level, i suppose i will have to always do like this doc.Descendents(a).Descendents(b).... so on